# Fetch api when like button is clicked

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-navigation

I have created a like icon on my front-end using react native, where I want it to post to the api as soon as the like icon is onclicked, hence I have created a separate likePress() function which contains an if statement, wherein only when clicked its color should change to red and should return the spi, however being a newbie am missing out on something.

The following is the snippet of my likePress()function:

```
     likePress = async() => {
    if (this.state.likeIcon == 'white') {
      this.setState({ likeIcon: 'red' }); 
    }    
    if (this.state.likeIcon == 'red') {
        fetch('some url' +product._id, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                like: this.state.product._id
            })

        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => {

            this.setState({ likeIcon: 'red', data: result })
            console.log(_id,'id')
          console.log(result,JSON.stringify({
            like: this.state.product._id
        }))
        }).catch(error => {
          alert(error);
          console.error(error);
        })
    }
}
```

And am calling this function inside the following which is inside a flatlist:

```
<TouchableOpacity
                onPress={this.likePress}
                style={{
                  alignItems: 'center',

                  borderRadius: 60,
                  padding: 10,
                }}>
                <Icon
                  name="heart"
                  size={30}
                  color={this.state.likeIcon}

                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
```

Please help me understand whether am doing it right or not.
Do tell me, if anything else is required, thank you.

My logs, right now:

```
 {"product": [{"__v": 0, "_id": "5e301696f75182463c6874ed", "color": "Space Grey", "colors": [Array], "description": "6.5-inch Super Retina XDR OLED display
Water and dust resistant (4 meters for up to 30 minutes, IP68)
Triple-camera system with 12MP Ultra Wide, Wide, and Telephoto cameras; Night mode, Portrait mode, and 4K video up to 60fps
12MP TrueDepth front camera with Portrait Mode, 4K video, and Slo-Mo
Face ID for secure authentication and Apple Pay
A13 Bionic chip with third-generation Neural Engine
Fast charge with 18W adapter included
Wireless charging
Manufacturer Detail: Apple Inc, One Apple Park Way, Cupertino, CA 95014, USA", "downloads": 2, "nameImg": "61jgfLBydjL._SL1024_-1580209807807.jpg", "nameVid": "videoplayback (1)-1580209807809.mp4", "price": 99900, "sellerID": "13755902031", "sellerName": "Appario", "size": "5.8-inch", "sizes": [Array], "title": "Apple iPhone 11 Pro", "typeImg": "image/jpeg", "typeVid": "video/mp4", "uploadedOn": "2020-01-28T11:10:14.244Z", "urlImg": "https://atiiproductmediafiles.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/61jgfLBydjL._SL1024_-1580209807807.jpg", "urlVid": "https://atiiproductmediafiles.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/videoplayback+%281%29-1580209807809.mp4"}, {"__v": 0, "_id": "5e30171df75182463c6874ee", "color": "Haze Blue", "colors": [Array], "description": "Rear Camera - 48MP (Primary) + 8MP (Tele-photo)+16MP (Ultrawide) | Front Camera - 16 MP POP-UP Camera
16.9 centimeters (6.67-inch) multi-touch capacitive touchscreen with 3120 x 1440 pixels resolution
Memory, Storage and SIM: 6GB RAM | 128GB internal memory | Dual SIM dual-standby (4G+4G)
Android Oxygen operating system with 2.84GHz Snapdragon 855 octa core processor
4000mAH lithium-ion battery
1 year manufacturer warranty for device and 6 months manufacturer warranty for in-box accessories including batteries from the date of purchase
Box also includes: Power Adapter, Type-C Cable (Support USB 2.0), Quick Start Guide, Welcome Letter, Safety Information and Warranty Card, Logo Sticker, Case, Screen Protector (pre-applied) and SIM Tray Ejector", "downloads": 1, "nameImg": "61FRLa8IFTL._SL1500_-1580209943294.jpg", "nameVid": "videoplayback-1580209943295.mp4", "price": 53999, "sellerID": "13755902031", "sellerName": "OnePlus", "size": "6.67 inch", "sizes": [Array], "title": "OnePlus 7T Pro", "typeImg": "image/jpeg", "typeVid": "video/mp4", "uploadedOn": "2020-01-28T11:12:29.918Z", "urlImg": "https://atiiproductmediafiles.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/61FRLa8IFTL._SL1500_-1580209943294.jpg", "urlVid": "https://atiiproductmediafiles.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/videoplayback-1580209943295.mp4"}, {"__v": 0, "_id": "5e3273ae32213d4ba037042a", "color": "assas", "colors": [Array], "description": "assa", "downloads": 0, "nameImg": "apex-legends-logo-1580364717181.jpg", "nameVid": "videoplayback (2)-1580364717241.mp4", "price": 222, "sellerID": "sas", "sellerName": "sasa", "size": "sdassa", "sizes": [Array], "title": "wws", "typeImg": "image/jpeg", "typeVid": "video/mp4", "uploadedOn": "2020-01-30T06:11:58.768Z", "urlImg": "https://atiiproductmediafiles.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/apex-legends-logo-1580364717181.jpg", "urlVid": "https://atiiproductmediafiles.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/videoplayback%20%282%29-1580364717241.mp4"}], "user": {"__v": 0, "_id": "5e300846241a3b1c89d654c4", "address": [], "changes": [], "checkout": [], "like": [], "mobile": 8697779335, "orders": [], "registeredOn": "2020-01-28T10:09:10.569Z"}}
```

As you can see it is not passing the product id but only fetching the first api that I have used to get the videos on view inside a flatlist.

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: `onPress={this.likePress()}` => `onPress={this.likePress}`

Comment: `fetch` returns a promise, so i can't see you are using the response data anywhere. That is one thing i can see is not good. and **Tim** has pointed that you need a reference but you are executing it.

Comment: I have made the changes added a promise that fetch should resturn as per your advice and made the changes as per @Tim,  Can you please now say whether this is enough or am missing out anything more?

Comment: @TRINACHAUDHURI i still can see `onPress={this.likePress()}`. Change it and see if that works other seems correct but first check for likeIcon seems unnecessary. meaning if icon is white then why setting it to white.

Comment: Hi, have updated with the edits please let me know if am missing out on anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are setting the likeIcon to red through `this.setState({ likeIcon: "red" })`you can not check if the state is set to red directly after `setState` because it is asynchronous (link to [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)).

You can replace that logic by using the boolean `isRed` provided below which will only call the API if the likeIcon's state was white before the button was pressed.

```
likePress = async () => {
        let isRed = false;
        if (this.state.likeIcon === "white") {
            this.setState({ likeIcon: "red" });
            isRed = true;
        }
        if (isRed) {
            try {
                const response = await fetch("some url" + product._id, {
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                    body: JSON.stringify({ like: this.state.product._id })
                });
                const json = await response.json();
                this.setState({
                    likeIcon: "red",
                    data: json
                });
                console.log(_id, "id");
                console.log(
                    result,
                    JSON.stringify({
                        like: this.state.product._id
                    })
                );
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        }
    };
```

I also changed it so that you are using `async await` instead of the callback functions which in my opinion makes the onPress a little easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify the function as below.

```
likePress = () => {
    if (this.state.likeIcon != 'white') {
        fetch('some url', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                like: this.state.product._id
            })
        }).then(result => {
            this.setState({ likeIcon: 'red' })
        }).catch(error => {
            //do something with error
        })
    }
}
```

This will update the state when response fetch successfully.

Comment: Hi, I have updated my function, please check and tell if am still missing out on anything

Comment: Do you have any error and the value of _id will be undefined 'console.log(_id,'id'). Post error as well if you facing any.@Trina Chaudhuri

Comment: No, am not getting any error neither is the api getting fetched or responding, even the log is not showing anything

Comment: I have made even more changes, yet it is not fetching the api, kindly help, please, I will even post the logs

Comment: Can you check url using postman and check if its working on postman@TRINA CHAUDHURI